# How to check if a key was pressed several times in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to now how to check if a key was pressed more times.I tried with the kbhit() function, but it returns when a key is pressed,only once.

Comment: Not a C++ pro here, but a similar problem exists in Java. The only way it can be solved there is by having a list of previous events, including their time and key. Then just inspecting the list. Might be something to consider.

Comment: `kbhit` is not a standard function - what platform/OS/compiler are you using ?

Comment: C++ has not the concept of a key. It depends on the operation system your program is running.

Comment: As others said, C++ natively doesn't provide a lot of functionality for capturing/controlling keyboard input. I would suggest you either use a third party library that handles low level stuff like this (SDL, SFML, Qt, etc.), or writing your own code through your OS API.